# Can you convert a table into a vararg without unpack?

Tags: lua, variadic-functions

Is there a way to return a numeric sequential table as a vararg without the use of unpack within lua? In other words; can you remake the unpack function?

Example table:

```
foo = {1, 2, 3}
```

Example function:

```
function unpackTable( tab )
    --
end
```

Requested result:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: How does it happen that `unpack` is unavailable in your Lua?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
local unpackTable do 

local function unpackTable_( tab, i, ... )
  if i == 0 then return ... end
  return unpackTable_( tab, i-1, tab[i], ...)
end

unpackTable = function( tab )
  return unpackTable_(tab, #tab)
end

end

foo = {1, 2, 3}
print(unpackTable(foo))
```